# How to prune low frequency and high frequency words from a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, pruning

Is there any tool available with which i can prune high frequency and low frequency terms from my dataset ?

Comment: Multiple tools are available. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @ChthonicProject i am working in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commonly used algorithm for this would be [Grubbs' test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grubbs%27_test_for_outliers). I don't really know an implementation in Java but if you would be willing to do the preprocessing in a different language, then there is the [outliers package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/outliers.pdf) in R containing amongst others the Grubbs' test. To eliminate multiple outliers you can just repeatedly apply Grubbs' test.

Edit:

I just saw that I missed the text classification tag. If you just want to keep too frequent terms from skewing your results, maybe [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) could be interesting to you. This of course does not reduce dimensionality.

Comment: thanx,  i am working in weka, it provides all functionalities however i was not sure about its pruning that is why i asked for a tool to only preprocess the documents to analyse the pruning results.

Comment: As far as I know Weka is a well established data mining tool. I think there is little reason to distrust their pruning. Is there something odd with their results that causes your distrust?

Comment: well weka is a very good tool but i don't understand a few things(may be because i am new to it). for e.g. in StringToWordVector class the function setWordsToKeep() we select words to keep in vocabulary but how would i know that how many features or words are in my dataset ? i.e. how would a know number of features/words in dataset of 20K docs in order to fill in setWordsToKeep function of StringToWordVector ?

Comment: Taken from [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) there should be an option (-M) to specify minimum term frequency. Furthermore, -stopwords supports the usage of stopwords or -S for a default list of stopwords.

Answer (score 0):

[Stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) are a common technique to eliminate (very) high frequency words in natural language processing.

Low-frequency words are usually interesting.  Do you actually want to eliminate them?

Comment: i have seen in papers some authors prune low frequency words i.e. words that occur in only 3 documents in entire datasets etc.

Comment: Fair enough.  Keeps the vocabulary count down I suppose.